# How to use arcpy.setValue for Title casing?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am trying to figure out how to use fieldName.title() method while updating rows using updateCursor for multiple fields. I was trying to improve the code of this post to fit my purpose:

[arcpy.UpdateCursor for multiple fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31056/arcpy-updatecursor-for-multiple-fields)

```
def ChangetoTitleCase(sourceTable, fieldNames):
      try:
        rows=arcpy.UpdateCursor(sourceTable)
        for row in rows:
          for fieldName in fieldNames:
            uField='"%s"' % fieldName
            row.setValue(uField, "uField.title()")
            rows.updateRow(row)
        del row, rows

      except Exception, e:
        import traceback, sys
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
        print e.message
```

I am working with Python 2.6.5, ArcPy 10 and Win 7 64. Please let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: What type of dataset is the "sourceTable" (i.e. shapefile, file geodatabase, sde...)?

Comment: Just to be clear here, is it correct that you are trying to set the value of the attribute to be equal to the attribute name?

Comment: No, I am trying to titleCase the contents of the field. Something which I did -and not working was rows.getValue(uField).title(). So, I tried to use the same method used in labelexpressions i.e. !FieldName!.title(). In this case !FieldName! is uField. Did I make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this line as follows:

```
def ChangetoTitleCase(sourceTable, fieldNames):
  try:
    rows=arcpy.UpdateCursor(sourceTable)
    for row in rows:
      for fieldName in fieldNames:
        newValue = (row.getValue(fieldName)).title()
        row.setValue(fieldName, newValue)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    del row, rows

  except Exception, e:
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked like a charm!!- I didn't use getValue correctly. Thanks a lot Jeremy!!!!! You're a life saver